# Faster way to show/hide ReactJS components? Toggle component or toggle display?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

Consider `<MenuComponent />` is the reusable component. Which code perform better in this scenario.

Option 1

```
render() {
   return this.state.shouldHidden ? null : <MenuComponent />
}
```

Option 2

```
render() {
   return <MenuComponent hidden={this.state.shouldHidden}/>
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct way to hide components in React.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44560074/correct-way-to-hide-components-in-react-js)

Answer (score 1):

Obviously 1. because if `hidden` at least one function call can be avoided.

But, seriously, it will save you only some microseconds.
Never forget: **premature optimization** is the root of all evil :)

Comment: If think of 'reflow'?